# Ajax stuck at before send

Tags: php, ajax

My Ajax Login form stuck at before send.

Which is the:

> beforeSend: function()

I have tried to display the error but there is no error at all as it keeps stuck at the beforesending. Is it because of my PHP not returning back any data and affecting the JavaScript?

Ajax Script:

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
/* validation */
$("#login-form").validate({
    rules:
    {

    },
    messages:
    {

    },
    submitHandler: submitForm
});
/* validation */
/* form submit */
function submitForm()
{
    var data = $("#login-form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url  : 'lgreg/post/login-post.php',
        data : data,
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $("#error").fadeOut();
            $("#login-submit").html('Logining ...');
        },
        success :  function(data)
        {
            if(data===0){

                $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){


                    $("#error").html('Please Activate Your Acount!');

                    $("#login-submit").html('Login');

                });

            }
            else if(data=="success")
            {

                $("#login-submit").html('Redirecting...');
                var delay = 1000; 
                setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "http://moonxyweb.com/emailconfirmation"; }, delay);

            }
            else{

                $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){

                    //$("#error").html('Error occur, Please Contact Our Support!');
                    $("#error").html(data);
                    $("#login-submit").html('Login');

                });

            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
/* form submit */

});
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 require_once 'dbconfig.php';

 if($_POST)
{
$user_name      = $_POST['user_name'];
$user_password  = $_POST['password'];
$lastlogin_date   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$password   = password_hash( $user_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 11));
$activation = "1";
try
{
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_name=:name AND activation=:activation");
    $stmt->execute(array(":name"=>$user_name , ":activation"=>$activation));
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($count==1){
        $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_name=:name AND user_password=:password");
        $stmt->execute(array(":name"=>$user_name , ":password"=>$user_password));
        $check_acc = $stmt->rowCount();
        if($check_acc == 1)
        {
            echo "success";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "wrong";
        }

    }
    else{
        echo "0";
    }

}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}


?>
```

Comment: Well does it even send the request to the php page or not?

Comment: And does it fade out #error and display the "Logining ..." in #login-submit?

Comment: It did have the display of logining but it does not prompt any error

Comment: you must have to use more settings for ajax call to perform full like 
complete:function(data,status){},error:function(data,status,error){}